# Nesting sumif in an if statement

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a formula that if the value of **Release** column in a table is "Demo", where the formula would perform a sumif to return result.  I have the sumif working, but can't seem to include the additional condition.   I thought it would be like this:  =if ('Release'!G:G="Demo",(sumif('User Stories'!G:G, A2,'User Stories'!F:F),"NA"))

Tables -

Source Table:
[image]
Formula Table - I want the value of the sumif shown ONLY where corresponding Release column of Source Table is = "Demo"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

=sumif('User Stories'!G:G, A3,'User Stories'!F:F)